# Compilation error after including vector in C++

Tags: c++

I am including vector as “#define ” in my cpp file. After compilation, it is showing that “No such file or directory”. Is there anything needs to be added to Android.mk makefile to compile for this?

Comment: _"I am including vector as “#define ” in my cpp file. "_ Huh what?

Comment: did you #include or #define? these are not the same thing.

Comment: Please, post a complete example, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to include `vector` is

```
#include <vector>
```

I have no clue what you mean with *including as `#define`*.

Comment: Now it is solved. I included path of vector from stlport from ndk folder of my build in my android.mk file. Also needed to include libstlport library to android.mk file